Changing the locality/language of a google maps widget on flutter without having to change the locality of the device itself
Using flutter and google_maps_flutter, I am trying to implement a map on my project.
However, I can't seem to find how to change the language in which the map should be displayed from within the code. The map only changes its language when the language of the device itself is changed.
I tried following the documentation on The official flutter documentation website, but to no avail.
Here is are snippets of what I have so far:
app.dart
    ...
    return MaterialApp(
      //debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Dummy',
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        DefaultMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('en'),
        Locale('he'),
      ],
      locale: const Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: 'he', countryCode: 'IL'),
    ...
    );

main_screen.dart:
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Row(
            Flexible(
              child: Localizations.override(
                context: context,
                locale: const Locale('he'),
                child: Builder(
                  builder: (context) {
                    // A toy example for an internationalized Material widget.
                    return GoogleMap(initialCameraPosition: defaultCameraPosition);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
  ...


Can you please provide the Flutter Google Maps package you're using?

@Kat It's google_maps_flutter
